# Is it possible to overload the implementation of a pure virtual function in the child class?

Tags: c++, oop, overriding, pure-virtual

I am working on a project in which I have a base class called `MSTAlgorithm` (Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm). Two classes called `PrimsAlgorithm` and `KruskalsAlgorithm` publically derive from this base class. I think this is correct as these two algorithms have an 'is-a' relationship to the base class - i.e they both *are* MST algorithms, just with slightly different implementations. By writing methods common to both algorithms in the base class I save having to rewrite code which is common to both algorithms and I can work with a pointer to base such as `std::unique_ptr<MSTAlgorithm> algorithm = std::make_unique<KruskalsAlgorithm>()` or `std::unique_ptr<MSTAlgorithm> algorithm = std::make_unique<PrimsALgorithm>()`.

I have the following method defined pure virtual on my base class (denoting that it must be implemented by any class deriving from this base class):

```cpp
class MSTAlgorithm {
  public:
    virtual std::queue<Edge> findMST(Node& startingNode) = 0; 
}
```

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible that I can implement `findMST` in the derived classes with different parameters, i.e overload this function. Due to the nature of how the algorithms work, Kruskals does not require a starting node, whereas Prims does. Is it possible to 'overload' pure virtual function implementations somehow?

The code below shows my intention, but does not compile because the compiler expects no parameter to be passed for `findMST` on `PrimsAlgorithm`:

```cpp
class KruskalsAlgorithm : public MSTAlgorithm {
  public:  
    std::queue<Edge> findMST();
}
```

```cpp
class PrimsAlgorithm : public MSTAlgorithm {
  public:
    std::queue<Edge> findMST(Node& startingNode);
}
```

Comment: by definition overriding requires to have the same signature. But in your case, if acceptable, you may replace the reference to Node (that should be const btw?) by a pointer to Node, defaulted to nullptr. Other design are possible according to your actual need. Are you sure, for instance, on all the possible parameters your various implementation may need? (otherwise, their are solutions also)

Comment: Use the [`override` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). It was added in C++11. It will help you figure out the answer.

Comment: The whole point of virtual member functions is possibility to call it without knowing any details of subclass implementing that member functions. So please explain to me when you have pointer of type `KruskalsAlgorithm *` which points to `PrimsAlgorithm` how you calling `findMST();` could invoke `findMST(Node& startingNode);`?

Comment: You need to provide an implementation of the pure virtual function as well.

Comment: Prim's algorithm starts with on an **arbitrary** node. I think in your case, you want `findMST` to have no parameter. Then, the first thing `PrimsAlgorithm::findMST` does is pick a starting node a random. If besides that method, you want to provide a method where the starting node is a parameter, you can, which means `Prims::findMST()` will most likely call `Prims::findMST(const Node& startingNode)`.

Comment: BTW, you may want to at least think about [NVI](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface); which tells you this is not a good idea. Be nice to your algorithms, give them the interfaces they want to have.

Comment: **Unrelated**: It seems strange to use polymorphism when using an algorithm. If you intend to use `PrimsAlgorithm` you should create a `PrimsAlgorithm` directly, and not hold it though a `MSTAgorithm*`.

Comment: Would removing the argument from `findMST` and providing it in PrismsAlgorithm via constructor be a valid solution? Then the `Base` class provides an interface that fits both algorithms. https://godbolt.org/z/naT76717j

Comment: `virtual std::queue<Edge> findMSG(std::any);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try to create an instance of `KruskalsAlgorithm`, you will see that you haven't overridden `findMST`, you have declared a different member. Because it inherits from `MSTAlgorithm` but doesn't provide `findMST(Node&)` you won't be able to create the instance.

To be able to use it polymorphically, the parameters have to match. You will have a call site like

```
std::unique_ptr<MSTAlgorithm> algorithm;
Node node;
algorithm->findMST(node);
```

I.e. there will always be a node passed. The easiest thing to do is to take a `Node&` parameter in `KruskalsAlgorithm` and do nothing with it.

I would also advise that you use the keyword `override` to denote member functions that you expect to be override virtual members in a base class, so that you are warned when they don't match, as you have here.

```
class KruskalsAlgorithm : public MSTAlgorithm {
  public:  
    std::queue<Edge> findMST(Node&) override;// Unnamed parameter because unused
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the existing answer. You have a problem with no good solution, only workarounds. This probably means that virtual methods are not a good tool for that part of your project.

A possible workaround for an additional unexpected parameter in a new child class, if you can't update the parent: make an additional method which receives and remembers the additional parameter(s). At call site, do your work in 2 stages — pass the new parameter, then call the regular overridden method.

You could even make a non-virtual method which does both things, and give it the same name as the virtual method, but this won't make it behave in a polymorphic way.

Comment: Agreed that the solution I have implemented is far from ideal. I'm going to look into how the STL or Boost implement algorithms. I think templated functions would be a better approach to solving this problem.